# Select all of pTable customize

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng, primeng-datatable

## Is there a way to customize select all of primeng p-table with ptableheadercheckbox remains checked on click with select all event with one less than total no of actual rows and if again select all of tableheadercheckbox got clicked it's checked should be false and now no rows should be selected...**your text**

ptableheadercheckbox remains checked on click with select all event with one less than total no of actual rows and if again select all of tableheadercheckbox got clicked it's checked should be false and now no rows should be selected...

The problem is that ptableheadercheckbox checked getting removed if I am changing selectedRows on click or select all event , I want that to be checked if one less than total no of rows got selected

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.